# NavigationController + Toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a NavController, but i enabled the toolbar at the bottom. I also added UIBarButtonItem and on the IB, it shows. It basiclly looks like

- Navigation Controller
- - Navigation Bar
- - Toolbar
- - Root View Controller
- - - Bar Button Item
- - - Navigation Item

So the Bar Button was added under Root View Controller, and i can see it in the IB where the Toolbar is, but when i run it, i can see the ToolBar, but not the Item which i called Item1 as its text!

Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always found it a better idea to deal with a NavigationController's toolbar programmatically rather than in Interface Builder for just these reasons.  The steps are

1. Tell the navigation controller to show the toolbar `[navController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]`.  Sounds like you've done this step.
2. Create your UIBarButtonItems.  Set your ViewController as the target of the bar buttons.
3. Add your bar button items to an NSArray.  Include buttonitems of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` or `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` to arrange them where you want on the toolbar.  Set the array to the toolbar's `items` property.
4. Write the methods that handle what happens when the user taps these buttons.
5. Make sure to release all these objects you've created as necessary.

No need to subclass anything.  Feel free to ask more if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: I realised, toolbar was the wrong thing, all i wanted was a toolbar type interface at the bottem to tell users that "internet is not connected" and was using the button to say that, but thats a bad idea now! I got another question about UIViews and how to make it like a toolbar so its a notification. But your right with your answer!

Comment: Newb question.. if you design it programmatically, would you see it in the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

You need Navigation Controller->ToolBar controller->RootViewContoller if you want to add the Bar button Item at the RootView Controller level.

Otherwise you have subclass the Tool Bar View, set up the IBOutlet for the tool bar button on that and do setButtonText method for the Button text. Then you can include that subclass in your Root View controller and call the setButtonText method.